# VS 2013: cannot add PCL NuGet package to compatible project due to dnxcore50 dependency

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package, portable-class-library, metrolog

I have VS 2013 and VS 2015 installed on my system.

With VS **2013**, I am currently developing a Profile 111 PCL project. The PCL target dialog looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to add a *NuGet* package ([MetroLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MetroLog/)), which contains dedicated assemblies for a number of platforms, **and** a Profile 259 PCL assembly, *portable-net45+wp8+win81+wpa81*.

Since Profile 111 targets a subset of Profile 259, it should be possible to install this *NuGet* package in my Profile 111 project. However, it does not! This is the error message I get instead:

[image]

So, the NuGet installer thus expects that the portable assembly in the NuGet package also target *dnxcore50*!

If I look in the list of supported frameworks for Profile 111 (*C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile111\SupportedFrameworks*), the target corresponding to *dnxcore50*, *ASP.NET Core 5.0* is indeed included (which I suppose is a consequence of a recent update of VS 2015?).

However, why is this affecting my ability to reference the PCL Profile 259 library from NuGet in my Profile 111 project?

And, is there anything I can do to override this behavior of the NuGet installation, other than manually removing the *ASP.NET Core 5.0.xml* file from the Profile 111 supported frameworks folder?

**NOTE 1** The library specification for the portable assembly in the *MetroLog* package (version 0.8.9) is actually incorrect. It states that *win81* is targeted, but it should really state *win* or *win8* or *netcore45*. However, I have modified the *.nupkg* file locally but a change to a correct *Windows 8* specification is not enough to make the NuGet accessible.

**NOTE 2** When attempting the same task in VS 2015, *ASP.NET Core 5.0* is displayed in the PCL target setup, and when selecting the other targets associated with Profile 111, the *Change Targets* dialog informs that *ASP.NET Core 5.0* will be automatically added to the list of supported targets. When trying to install the *MetroLog* NuGet package, the error message is instead that *MetroLog* does not contain any profile compatible with PCL Profile 111. Different paths, same end result...

**UPDATE** With VS 2015, I have found that the only issue is the invalid *win81* specification in the *portable* folder path. Is this is changed to a valid PCL Profile 111 target, i.e. *win8* (or the equivalents *win* or *netcore45*), I am allowed to use the NuGet package in my Profile 259 project. In VS 2015, the NuGet component sufficiently identifies the PCL profile as long as the sub-components are correctly specified, regardless of whether *dnxcore50* is listed or not.